# Yii throwing exception

Tags: yii, ckeditor, yii-extensions

An app that seems fine in local throwing me following exception on live:

```
CException

Alias "application.extensions.TheCKEditor.theCKEditorWidget" is invalid. 
Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.
```

Code:

```
   <?php $this->widget('application.extensions.TheCKEditor.theCKEditorWidget',array(
        'model'=>$model,                # Data-Model (form model)
        'attribute'=>'wordMeaning',         # Attribute in the Data-Model
        'height'=>'400px',
        'width'=>'100%',
        'toolbarSet'=>'Full',          # EXISTING(!) Toolbar (see: ckeditor.js)
        'ckeditor'=>Yii::app()->basePath.'/../assets/ckeditor3.6.5/ckeditor.php',
                                        # Path to ckeditor.php
        'ckBasePath'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/assets/ckeditor3.6.5/',
                                        # Relative Path to the Editor (from Web-Root)
        //'css' => Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/css/index.css',
                                        # Additional Parameters
    ) ); ?>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you verified that that file exists on the live server?

Comment: Check path ./protected/extensions/TheCKEditor/theCKEditorWidget. Also check case of path `TheCKEditor`

Comment: @WillemRenzema : file exists.

Comment: @Vainglory07 : I have updated the question with code

Comment: have you tried using 

'application.extensions.*'

in import section of main config arrays ?

Comment: @Sergey : you are correct. The extension file name case was TheCKEditorWidget and it was called like theCKEditorWidget. Changing case solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check path ./protected/extensions/TheCKEditor/theCKEditorWidget. Also check case of path TheCKEditor

Answer (score 1):

The extension file name was **TheCKEditorWidget.php** and it was called like **theCKEditorWidget.php**

Changing case solved my problem.